# jvm not found android studio windows

Tags: android, cordova

jvm not found android studio windows 8 when lunch android studio.i am config JAVA_HOME correctly. Please check Image.

[image]

how can i solve these.

```
      Thanks
```

Comment: use _PATH_ instead of _JAVA_HOME_

Comment: Path variables are correct.Please check above image

Comment: I am given both  path and JAVA_Home.But same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your reference image you give ***jre*** path in environment variable not ***jdk***.
You have to change your environment variable with ***jdk*** path is below as per your reference image.

[image]

Comment: Hi Pranay.Now it showing android studio loading and again close automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i do got the same problem , simple way is first uninstall the java from your control panel and the related one .And re install the new java. and in you studio  file->project structure->jdk loaction please setup you path properly if you and studio is old then 1.2 please install new studio it has jdk location

Comment: Hi Sathish,When i launch studio it showing these "msiexec is not recognized as an internal android studio"

Comment: please check your java path properly